# Question about OOP and objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oop, relational-database

I have a school assignment: a Dog Show.

My assignment is to create a website, where vistors can display results, and where Judges and Secretary can admin and CRUD.

I have a small problem, one part of the assignment: the result should be based on two decisions from different judges, and after that checked by the secretary, before the result is displayed for the user.

I have to say I'm fairly new to programming, and so I need some smart suggestions on how to design and implement this. The assignment should cover both a DB and C# (.NET MVC).

Q1: How do i create a object (result) that depends on two other objects (judge's decisions)? Is that even needed?

Q2: How to solve this in a relational db?

Comment: I find it really hard to believe that you haven't covered this in school. Your notes, or, if nothing else, your text books should have everything you need. Professors don't tend to assign projects based on material that students are ill-equipped to handle on their own. You don't seem to have any idea of what your professor is asking you. What have you done so far to work towards completion of the assignment?

Comment: i'm sry for upsetting you and my english isn't as good as it could be. I probably could solve this without asking a question,  i have some ideas that probably would work, programming is liberal in that way. But if you don't mind i like the idea of asking for design and implementation tips in areas I don't feel safe!

Comment: You'll find that people tend to be much more willing to guide you if you show some work you've done already. That should help alleviate the down votes too :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this would be hard to solve using a relational DB.  I'd suggest that you consider each table in the database as representing an entity (class) in your object model.  Some entities that you might want to consider Dog Show, Dog, Entry, Judgement, Result, Judge, Secretary (Judge/Secretary might both be an Official).  According to your definition, each Entry would have 2 Judgements (thus you should have a 1-to-Many relationship there), but each Entry only has 1 Result.  You might use code or a database constraint (or both) to ensure that a Result for an Entry isn't created until there are two Judgements for that Entry.  Likewise, you might use code/constraint to ensure that no more than two Judgements are entered for each Entry.

Hope this helps get you started.

Comment: Thank's it will help. Any tip or example on how to implement this constraint (or code)?

"You might use code or a database constraint (or both) to ensure that a Result for an Entry isn't created until there are two Judgements for that Entry. Likewise, you might use code/constraint to ensure that no more than two Judgements are entered for each Entry."

Comment: Count the number of Judgements before you allow a Result to be entered?  You could do this in the DB with a trigger or check constraint.  Pretty easy to do in code, though you want to make sure it's in a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

> How do i create a object (result) that depends on two other objects (judge's decisions)? Is that even needed?

I suggest that you create the result object, when you create the 2nd decision object.

The pseudocode might be something like, when the judge tries to create a new decision, then see how many other decisions already exist:

- case 0: this is the first decision; just create the new decision and return
- case 1: this will be the second decision; create the new decision, and then create the result based on the two decisions
- case 2 or more: two decisions already exist, so don't allow this further decision to be created.

Another (perhaps not so good) possibility is to have a separate "create results" process, which runs continually (not continuously: e.g., once every minute), looking for any already-created decision-pairs for which there's no corresponding result, and creating the corresponding result.